# ¿Como almacenar un Future<Dynamic> en una variable? Dart

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, vscode

Tengo una consulta sobre algo que no puedo solucionar.
Tengo un método que me genera una ID de producto, luego de hacer una query en firestore (el método lo muestro a continuación)

```
_obtenerCodProd(tipo) async {

    final QuerySnapshot snapshot = await Firestore.instance
        .collection('productos')
        .where("tipo", isEqualTo: tipo.toString())
        .getDocuments();

    String idLetra;

    if (tipo == "Snack") {
      idLetra = "SNK";
    }
    if (tipo == "Fruta") {
      idLetra = "FRU";
    }
    if (tipo == "Lácteo") {
      idLetra = "LAC";
    }
    if (tipo == "Líquido") {
      idLetra = "LIQ";
    }
    if (tipo == "Café") {
      idLetra = "CAF";
    }

    var cantidad_tipo = int.parse(snapshot.documents.length.toString());
    String idnumerico;
    int sumaID;
    sumaID = cantidad_tipo + 1;
    if (sumaID < 10) {
      idnumerico = "00$sumaID";
    }
    if (sumaID >= 10) {
      idnumerico = "0$sumaID";
    }
    if (sumaID >= 100) {
      idnumerico = "$sumaID";
    }
    print("cantidad_tipo: $cantidad_tipo");
    print("idnumerico: $idnumerico");

    return "Codigo de producto: $idLetra$idnumerico";
  }
```

Lo que me retorna ese metodo es un codigo de prducto.

[image: Aquí se muestra con "Codigo de producto" lo que retorna el metodo]

Pero cuando trato de almacenar ese return en una variable, y le hago un print, me dice que es un Future

```
// ALMACENAR ID PRODUCTO //
            var resultado = _obtenerCodProd(tipoSeleccionado);
            print(resultado);
```

[image: Este es el future]

Necesito almacenar ese Future que seria la id del producto, pero cuando lo almaceno y le hago un print me aparece que es un Future y no el valor que yo necesito en realidad.
Si hago un print directamente al metodo, tambien me muestra en pantalla que es un Future.
Pero aun así logre hacer que el print directamente al metodo me mostrara el varlo que quiero, pero no logro almacenarlo.
Por favor si pudieran ayudarme con eso, estaría muy agradecido
Muchas gracias de antemano

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1):

Lo que te está retornando es un `Future` porque es una petición asíncrona, lo que debes hacer es esperar por el resultado usando `await`.

Es decir, lo que implícitamente te está retornando `_obtenerCodProd` ese método es :

`Future<String> _obtenerCodProd`.

Cómo obtienes el `String`? Usando `async`/`await` así :

```
tuMetodo() async {

var resultado = await _obtenerCodProd(tipoSeleccionado);
            print(resultado);

}
```

Ahora `resultado` será un `String`.
Te recomiendo que revises `FutureBuilder` , `StatefulWidget`, `StreamBuilder`, son widgets que te podrían servir.

Answer (score 0):

El "snapshot" esta bien resuelto, porque retorna un Future y lo estás resolviendo en la misma variable anteponiendo "await". Ahora el problema puede estar en la variable "cantidad_tipo", al llamar "snapshot.documents", "documents" puede ser otro Future y no lo estás resolviendo. Finalmente cuando vayas a llamar a "_obtenerCodProd", que es un Future por "async", deberas resolverlo de la misma manera, si vas a implementar en la ui:

```
FutureBuilder<String>(
    future: _obtenerCodProd("Fruta"),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
        // Logica...
    }
)
```